# Trouble installing EasyGUI into Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, setup.py, anaconda, easygui

I'm trying to add `EasyGUI` into Anaconda but running into a problem.  I keep getting invalid syntax errors I think because I'm not writing out the file directory correctly. I know after putting the path (`C:\Users\User1\Downloads\easygui-0.96`) I'm supposed to put `"python setup.py install`"
So how would I write out that entire line?

I'm running Windows 8 if that matters.

I know I'm probably asking the dumbest question of the day/week/month/year, but I've just never used Anaconda. ;)

Comment: Did I ask a monumentally harder question than I originally thought?

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get it to work is to update your sys.path near the top of your program.  This may not be the "best" way to install things but it will work fine.  Something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Users\User1\Downloads\easygui-0.96')
import easygui
f = easygui.fileopenbox()
print(f)
```